# Is there any way to put a scrollbar inside a menubuton in Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, fonts, scrollbar

I have been trying to make an application in which you can choose between several fonts for a text. For this I have been using `Tkinter` and in the main window I have a menu button with all the possible fonts that you can choose from. There are about 347 fonts to choose from and I would like to put a scrollbar for scrolling inside the menu.

My code without the scrollbar is as follows:

```py
# Menu button
fonts_MenuButton = tk.Menubutton(main_window, text="v", bg="WHITE", fg="BLACK", activebackground="WHITE", font=("Arial", 9), relief=FLAT) # Menu for choosing font

fonts_MenuButton.pack(side="left", fill="x", expand=False) # Position the menu in which you can choose any font

fonts_MenuButton.menu = Menu(fonts_MenuButton, tearoff = 0) # Create a menu
fonts_MenuButton["menu"] = fonts_MenuButton.menu

# Fonts
fonts_MenuButton.menu.add_command(label=font_name1, font=(font_name1, 13), command=font1) # Font 1 button
fonts_MenuButton.menu.add_command(label=font_name2, font=(font_name2, 13), command=font2) # Font 2 button
fonts_MenuButton.menu.add_command(label=font_name3, font=(font_name3, 13), command=font3) # Font 3 button
fonts_MenuButton.menu.add_command(label=font_name4, font=(font_name4, 13), command=font4) # Font 4 button
fonts_MenuButton.menu.add_command(label=font_name5, font=(font_name5, 13), command=font5) # Font 5 button
fonts_MenuButton.menu.add_command(label=font_name6, font=(font_name6, 13), command=font6) # Font 6 button
fonts_MenuButton.menu.add_command(label=font_name7, font=(font_name7, 13), command=font7) # Font 7 button
...
```

In the places where it says, for example, `label=font_name1`, the variables starting with `font_name` are the variables where I store the font name.
And functions like `font1`, are the functions that are used when pressing the menu buttons.

Here is a picture to show you how it looks without the scroll bar:
[image: Menu without scroll bar]

And here's another one so you can see how I'd like it to look with the scroll bar:
[image: Menu with scroll bar]

Is there any way to do what I am asking? Thank you.

Comment: Why not use a listbox widget?

Comment: @Hermann12 And how could I put buttons inside that listbox?

Comment: You should be able to bind the ListBoxSelect event, no need to use a button `listbox.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', callback)`

Comment: @Alexander. You have to create your own DLL library.